# Delete first few rows containing merged cells

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am working on some VBScript that combines data from a bunch of excel files in a certain directory.  All of these excel files contain anywhere from 10-20 merged cells with useless information.

How can I tell it to delete just the merged cells at the beginning?

Thanks,

Andrew

Solution:

```
Sub RemoveMergedCells()
    For Each Cell In Range("A1:Z10")
        If Cell.MergeCells = True Then
            Set objRange = Cell.EntireRow
            Cell.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Merged cells are a real pain in VBA.  Can you provide more detail as to the format and number of occurrences?  Screen shot perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. (In this example it will only check Rows 1 to 10 and columns up to Z)

```
Sub RemoveMergedCells()
    For Each Cell In Range("A1:Z10")
        If Cell.MergeCells = True Then
            Cell.UnMerge
            Cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: hstay, that is very close to what I'm looking for.  I see that it just clears the contents of the merged cells, I'm looking to delete those rows entirely.  I tried using Cell.Delete instead of Cell.ClearContents, but that does not work

Comment: Was able to come up with a solution using this!

Answer (score -1):

probably this will do:

```
cell.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlDown
```

I put this in wrong place; you should wrap above code with one posted by hstay.